# Packet-Tracer multiple IPs for a PC

Tags: vlan, ip, packet-tracer, virtual

I searched for a way to configure a PC with multiple IP addresses in Packet Tracer but i found nothing. I read that you can use the command *netsh* on Windows to create virtual interfaces. I've tried to use this command with a command prompt, but Packet Tracer doesn't implement all the functionalities that it has in Windows.

So i'm stuck. I need a simple PC to have multiple IP addresses with a single physical interface, is there a way to do it in Packet Tracer ?

---

Edit : The purpose is :

I have a PC named *PC-X*, and two VLANs :

1. VLAN *1* associated with the subnet *10.39.253.0/27*.
2. VLAN *2* associated with the subnet *10.39.253.64/28*.

I want *PC-X* to be part of both VLAN *1* and *2*.

I thought about having two interfaces in *PC-X* : *eth0* and *eth1*. *eth0* would be configured with an IP address of the first subnet, and *eth1* with an IP address of the second. The problem is that i can only have one interface per PC in Packet Tracer, so i thought about configuring *eth0* to be the physical interface and *eth1* as a virtual interface.

In addition, to allow frames of multiple VLANs to cross the port of *PC-X*, I thought that i should configure the port in mode trunk. But i don't know of PCs in Packet Tracer accept 802.1q frames.

Comment: I have checked PT 5.3.2 and confirmed that the config indeed only allows one IP to be configured, not sure about newer version. Yes indeed CMD on PT is very limited, this is not a Win or Linux OS. I'm still confused at what you are trying to achieve by having the requirements you specified, kindly expand.

Comment: @DRP Thank you for your answer, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll base my answer solely on PT 5.3.2. and personal testing.
Answer is No.

You cannot assign 2 IP addresses due to the fact that the module cards are only accounted for one connection (i.e PT-HOST-NM-1FGE). Below you can see the list of modules:

[image: Modules]

On this other image just where you basically setup a static address or dhcp:

[image]

Now being said that let me clarify a couple of things:

- PC's do not do the tagging (vlan assignment), this is done on the incoming interface of the  connected device (i.e switch)
- Trunk ports account for tagged traffic, so you would need somehow to get traffic already tagged when received by the directly connected device which would imply that the PC has some sort of 802.1q mechanism. Check [How to assign single port into multiple vlans](https://serverfault.com/questions/152345/how-to-assign-single-port-into-multiple-vlans#152422)

Finally let us recall that although PT is good for learning it is somewhat limited.

For more advance research, testing and learning GNS3 might be a good option for you. Cheers!

**EDIT ADDED FROM HERE BELOW**

I have just got my hands with PT Version 7.0.0.0306, issue with PC is the same it only allows one network module to be installed and hence one IP.

However, something I noticed on the newer version and forgot to check on the old version is that the server does indeed support the adding of two cards, hence two IP addresses.

Unfortunately that does still not accomplish what you are looking for:

> I need a simple PC to have multiple IP addresses with a single physical interface, is there a way to do it in Packet Tracer ?

Anyways just thought of throwing that in out there. Kind Regards.